# Which database is the best for my situation?

Tags: database

I have a simple plan: I have a **one** application to create records and insert to database (2 - 10 record per second) and **3 or more** application (as clients) connect to DBMS server to query (`SELECT` statements for search and filter results) records rapidly

I don't use these SQL commands: delete, update. My records grows up to **2 billion!**

With this specification, can someone suggest which database is best for my situation?

- MySQL,
- MS-SQL Server,
- Oracle,
- or any other?

Comment: Could you add some information on the platform of your application?

Comment: depends on which amount of money you want to spend on it... add more details of your platform...

Comment: Depends on the nature of the `SELECT` - is it a simple query or does it have a nested subquery (that rules out MySQL as an efficient system, unless you redesign that query)? With proper use of indexes every product mentioned should be fine. I would also add PostgreSQL to that list. Also make sure you aren't too restrictive about the memory and file cache the RDBMS is set up to use. It can have great influence on speed.

Comment: I am working on Windows (xp) platform, And mony is not important for me.

Answer (score 1):

Our experiences with MySQL were not very nice when dealing with huge number of records. (2 million records is huge) I feel MySQL would not be the best choice with so frequent inserts either.

MS-SQL is better, says my colleagues at work. Then your DBMS server will have to be Windows based. It's your call to decide whether it is a problem or not.

You can not go wrong with Oracle. But it is very expensive.

You should have a seperate database access layer in your application, define an interface for all your database operations. If you use .NET, entity framework will make your life easier. Once you do these, you will be able to experiment with different databases relatively easily. At least in theory.

Just my two cents.

Edit: **2 Billion ??!**

If you really need that many records, this is my one line answer: **Hire an expert**.

Comment: Yes, of course :-) What I mean is, if you have experts on the team and don't care about the costs you will never say "I wish we choosed BlaBla instead of Oracle; it would be more performant"

Comment: Thank you,I really need to insert more and more records to DB, i manually insert on my MYSQL DB 10 million records, when i "SELECT *" take 18sec to retrieve all of my records. I really want some test results for average insert/select time diagram for my usage.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is free, but actively supported/maintained. I have used it with about 10+ million rows in the main table of our application and it was fine. It also has some funky SQL extensions - you can do stuff with it that's simple and effective that you can't do in other DBs (or it's extremely painful to do).

MS-SQL is IMHO not worth paying for - like most (all?) MS products they start with a "small" mentality (departmental system size) then retrofit concurrency and scalability and wonder why stuff doesn't work.

Oracle is obscenely expensive, but it's easy to get contractor staff to help you (they follow the money) and it's a very mature rock-solid product.

Another option is postgres, which I have used a lot. I really like postgres - it's free, and very solid. There is one caveat - it only recently bundled real-time, failover replication into its offering - something that mysql has had for many years.

I would go MySQL and see what happens.

Comment: MySQL can be free...not always true

Comment: Price is not important for me, i am trying to make a decision for software productions of my company, that, which DBMS is the best (for this solution).